# Codename One App Subscription submitReceipt not called

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

We are making use of Renewable subscriptions in one of our apps and for some reason the Submit Receipts method on the Receipt Store is not being fired after the native OS completes its steps.

Here is a spinet of our code,

```
iap = Purchase.getInAppPurchase();

        ReceiptStore store = new ReceiptStore() {
            @Override
            public void fetchReceipts(SuccessCallback<Receipt[]> callback) {
               //Not important for the example
            }

            @Override
            public void submitReceipt(Receipt receipt, SuccessCallback<Boolean> callback) {
                 EMCDialogFactory.showMessageDialog("Subscription Succeeded", "Your app will now close, please restart the app for your subscription to be activated");

                    callback.onSucess(true);

                    //Store receipt on phone and sent to server

                    Display.getInstance().exitApplication();
            }
        };

        iap.setReceiptStore(store);
        iap.synchronizeReceipts();
```

Any idea what we are doing wrong.

Comment: Where is this code defined in your app? In which callback?
Did you test it in both physical devices?

Comment: We have a static helper class that holds all our subscription code. After the user logs in we fire a load method that initialise the as shown above.

Comment: We also implemented the PurchaseCallback on our main class. All the methods simple display a dialog to inform us what happened.

Comment: Using dialogs is a bad idea here since some of these callbacks can happen before you have a UI and dialog might block execution. Try using a logger to save the data and provide a way for the developer to look at the logged data easily. That would be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks Shai, we had two problems, 1 was that we had the incorrect Android License key in our build hints (Sorry, should have checked before asking) and 2 was the Dialog being called before the UI was available. Thank for the help!